# Not able to moderate Facebook comments on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, comments

I've put the code for Facebook comments on my website: www.weloveisrael.org (down at the bottom).
I can't seem to be able to moderate them, this is the code, what am I missing? :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="518305576" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{224255590957777}"/>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#admins=518305576&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="http://www.weloveisrael.org"  reverse="0" num_posts="10" width="960"></fb:comments>
```

Comment: What do you mean? what Java? do I need to add java somewhere? what\how?

Comment: What is the first tag listed for this question?

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added the comments box code correctly:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));</script>
<fb:comments href="example.com" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

Then, between the  HTML tags in your file (near the top), add the following:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="518305576" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="224255590957777"/>
```

You can check that you've done this correctly by entering your web page in the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: b.t.w on a different subject, any idea, if at all possible, how can I set what image FB will show when someone is sharing my website?
Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can add the og:image tag (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). If you think this answer is acceptable, please vote up. :)